# Copied text in iOS Stack Exchange app pastes as weird data file in Notes app

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios

When I copy a "comment" or "post" using the Stack Exchange app in iOS 13.3.1, and paste it in my Notes app, it pastes as a weird data file with what seems to be a GUID with random numbers inside of it. Why is this happening, what does it mean, and what is it doing? How can I look at the contents of the pasted file?

See screenshot and imgur video link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9BZf.jpg

[image: notes app with weird data file inside on ios]

Comment: If you paste the same data into a text message or into the body of an email, what appears? Do you have other apps with note-taking capabilities such as Dropbox or Evernote on which you can test? Also - try adding some text into a Notes note first, then paste the data. What happens?

Comment: This only seems to happen if you use the „Copy“ function within the app, not if you select the text directly by highlighting it? Looks like a bug in the app to me

Comment: iOS 13.3.1? Do you mean 12.3.1? I have 12.4 and can't reproduce it for posts, only for comments.

Comment: @gorfindel me too, the copy function seems to be available for comments only anyway

Comment: One more nail in the app coffin.

Comment: I can reproduce on iOS 12.4 for comments. If you try pasting into iMessage it doesn’t paste anything.

Comment: @ShaWiz or justification to have a revamp... I’d be gutted if the app got binned, I do most of my browsing using it.

Comment: @Notts90 it's like using IE6, or Windows 95. It's ancient app, no longer supported by the people who developed it, and keeps falling apart slowly but surely. ;(

Comment: @Notts90 I can verify the same result with imessage pasting

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, 12.3.1 sorry